# Option select with reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 Models: Unit and Emp
Also I have 2 controllers: Units and Emps

```
class CreateEmps < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :emps do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :unit

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :units do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Looks simple.... but I guess too simple. I haven't found example how to do the following:

I need to have form for Emp creation.

So my question is .... how should it look like?

I want to have ComboBox with list of all objects in Units.

```
<%= form_with model: @emp do |f| %>
<p><%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %> </p>
<!-- What should go here? to ComboBox (option->select) -->
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    <% end %>
```

I am also confused how should it look like regargding emp_params for permiting.

EDIT:

```
class EmpsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @emp = Emp.new
    @unit_options = Unit.all.collect{|unit| [unit.name, unit.id] }
  end

  def create
    @emp = Emp.new(emp_params)
    @emp.save
    redirect_to :action => :list
  end

  def destroy
    @emp = Emp.find([:id])
    @emp.destroy
    redirect_to :action => :list
  end

  def list
    @emps = Emp.all
  end

  def emp_params
    params.require(:emp).permit(:name, :unit_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by ComboBox? You’ve defined that EMP belongs to one Unit so why not just use a select box?

Comment: <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

Comment: I was previously programming in C# so there it was called combobox

Comment: Gotcha, answer coming up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [select tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).

In your controller:

```
@unit_options = Unit.all.collect{|unit| [unit.name, unit.id] }
```

This creates a list of names and IDs, the order of each is name then value for the select option. You can of course scope or filter the results as needed.

In your view:

```
<%= form_with model: @emp do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :unit_id, 'Unit' %>
    <%= f.select :unit_id, @unit_options, {include_blank: true} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

When used to edit the model, rails will select the option for the current value.

Comment: Indeed that kinda did the trick. Thanks. Altough now I am experiencing some different issue it doesn't seem to save in DB. altough there is no error.

Comment: Could you please take a look? I provided full controller definition

Comment: Nevermind ... It was wrong association (had to use has_one)
Big thanks for solution and merry christmass ;)